# Запуск демона sphinxsearch на Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, sphinx, сервер

Добрый день.Установил на ubuntu server поисковый движок sphinx. Создал тестовую БД, которая идёт в комплекте. На ней запустил индексацию и попробовал делать запросы из командной строки, всё работает. Теперь хочу запустить демона, даю команду:    service sphinxsearch startи получаю такой результат. ![alt text][1][Вот][2] мой conf файл. Подскажите что делать, что бы его запустить ?  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oASJB.png  [2]: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9133112/linux/sphinx.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если запустить `netstat -al` и посмотреть нет ли на 9312 ничего. `bind() failed` чаще всего из-за таких ситуаций бывает.